# SAML / OAUTH redirect URL clarification

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am working on a SSO application with SAML / OAuth and I am not sure if i understand the meaning of the redirect/callback url at all. So lets take SAML as an example.

I have a typical SAML config:

```
IDPLoginURL : "https://myidp/login",
Issuer: "myhost",
RedirectURL: ?
Certificate: "MII....."
```

I always see the diagrams and descriptions where the redirect url points to the resource server or the service provider. But i have different endpoints on a service, now i am confused.

I have endpoints on myhost for resources which need a saml token for access:

```
GET myhost/service1
GET myhost/service2
```

Wouldn't i need two different redirect URLs now?

I am using: https://github.com/steffow/meteor-accounts-saml

Can someone give me a bit clarification here.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>The redirect URL is used as a way for your application to receive the outcome of the authentication process. Your application delegates this authentication to a third-party and then the result is communicated by invoking your configured redirect URL.</sub>

<sub>How to handle this redirect is application specific, for example, a regular server-side Web application could initiate a login session upon receiving confirmation that the user logged in. Usually, this session would be created by issuing a session cookie based on the information the identity provider (using SAML, OpenID Connect or event OAuth 2.0) sent. The following requests would send the created cookie and the application would authorize those requests purely based on it with no involvement of the identity provider.</sub>

In your scenario, it seems **you have a Web API that requires access tokens to grant access** and then I imagine there will be one or more **client application** that want to call the endpoints exposed by this API. This would be an textbook OAuth 2.0 scenario, where the redirect URL would be of the client application wanting to access your API. As soon as the redirect URI is called, the application would store the access token so it could then call each endpoint separately, but always using the same token.

**Your confusion probably comes from the fact that you might checked some diagrams that were not aimed at your exact scenario**. Assuming, the scenario of an application wanting to call into a protected API, you can check this diagram:

[image: SPA using OAuth 2.0 implicit grant to access Web API]

(source: [SPA + API Scenario](https://auth0.com/docs/architecture-scenarios/application/spa-api))

In this case the redirect URL would be one for the SPA app and it would be called as part of the interaction leaving Auth0 (identity provider/authorization server) and going to the SPA application.

Comment: Would this also apply for SAML 2.0 as well?

Comment: It can, just have in mind that generally SAML is an authentication protocol and OAuth 2.0 is more authorization specific. A token from SAML proves that the user is who he says he is, an access token from OAuth 2.0 proves he has access to a given resource. You can rely on the identity token to grant access to the API and it works, OAuth 2.0 would just be more suitable (and possibly more time consuming to setup).